# Disable STP and force port state on a Avaya 4950 switch port

Tags: switch, spanning-tree, avaya

I know how to connect a switch on a router Avaya VSP 7200 by disabling STP with the command :

```
no spanning-tree mstp force-port-state enable
```

but how to force port state on a switch Avaya 4950?

Thank you for helping

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: No solution
We'll probably try a reboot but i don't know when

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the 4900, but on the 5000 (5xxx) line I use the following:

```
interface FastEthernet ALL
spanning-tree rstp port 21-22 learning disable
exit
```

(21 is a cablemodem, 22 is the router)

STP will show the ports as `Discarding`, but they aren't:

```
troz-5510-1#show spanning-tree rstp port role 21-22
Port     Role       State     STP Status  Oper Status
----  ----------  ----------  ----------  -----------
21    Disabled    Discarding  Disabled    Disabled     
22    Disabled    Discarding  Disabled    Disabled 

troz-5510-1#show interfaces 21-22 
              Status                    Auto                       Flow  
Port Trunk Admin   Oper Link LinkTrap Negotiation Speed    Duplex Control
---- ----- ------- ---- ---- -------- ----------- -------- ------ -------
21         Enable  Up   Up   Enabled  Enabled     1000Mbps Full   Disable 
22         Enable  Up   Up   Enabled  Enabled     1000Mbps Full   Asymm
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

I need to connect a switch small switch (hp procurve) on my Avaya 4900 because RJ45 outlet are missing in our office.

this command above shows that the port state is fowarding. So my issue seems not to come from spanning tree : one switch port seems desactivated but i don't know why.

Avaya switch is sending LLDP (first frame) to the device which is connected on but then it doesn't send the BOFL frame which seems to be necessary to establish the connexion.
Then the device get no answer to his broadcasts and don't receive the broadcasts of others devices.

Comment: Thank you, that also helped me to be sure I'm not messing things up badly ;)